# Windows Store Apps / Windows Phone 8, MonoGame alternative?

Tags: c#, windows-8, game-engine, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8

I am currently analyzing different Game Engine to use with C# on Windows Store Apps and Windows Phone.

Not that I have anything against MonoGame(I worked a lot with XNA in the past), but I always prefer to have more than one option.

What would be the best free/paid alternative to MonoGame/SharpDX to develop Game, using C#, targeting Windows Store Apps and Windows Phone 8?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Best" how? What kind of game are you doing? A 3D shooter? 2D side-scroller? What kind of "engine"? Graphics? Physics? AI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't be afraid to reconsider Monogame. It's open source, so you can do whatever you need to with it. I was able to port my two games, Cloud Blaster and Cyber Attack, with very minimal code changes. Most of it was just menu interfaces and keyboard controls. Using Monogame is just like using XNA.

Aside from those already mention, Unreal Engine 3 is either going to support the store, or it already does. NVidia demoed it a few months back, so it might be something worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

Unity 3D for windows 8 is coming soon, so you might want to wait for that.

[Cocos2D](http://cocos2d-x.org/news/54), [Construct2 by Scirra](http://www.scirra.com/tutorials/272/how-to-make-a-windows-8-metro-app/page-1), [Havok](http://havok.com/news-and-press/releases/havok-showcase-full-technology-suite-windows-8-windows-rt-and-windows-phone), [Marmalade](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/windows8/), and Ogre are also coming to Windows 8/Windows Phone 8.